# tabcontrol background image in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I want to put background image from tabcontrol in c# winforms. How can i change it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a background image on the `TabControl` itself ; the `TabControl.BackgroundImage` property exists, but has no effect.

However you can put a background image on a page of the `TabControl` :

```
tabControl1.TabPages[0].BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(fileName);
```

Comment: Interesting that it has a BackgroundImage property that doesn't work.  Begging to be extended.

Comment: That's because this property is defined in the `Control` class, and `TabControl` inherits from `Control`. But it makes no sense for `TabControl`, since its background will be hidden by the `TabPages` anyway. On `TabControl`, the property is hidden in designer and Intellisense.

Comment: It is hidden if TabPages exist, which is true in most cases. But if you removed all TabPages, the Background Image actually could be shown. Don't know whether it is.